# How to create a download link for a file using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, download

In my job portal project, I have stored the job seekers data in MySQL Database. I have stored their uploaded resumes in the upload folder. I am able to retrieve that data of job seekers for the employers through pagination. And I want to create a download resume link of each job seeker with his data in the pagination result. How I can add the download resume link for the resume files from upload folder with each search result in the pagination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the solution here: http://www.ssdtutorials.com/tutorials/title/download-file-with-php.html

As the file which I want to download is dynamic associated with each job seeker's data. I used while loop for retrieving the file name from database.

```
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        $filename = $row[0];
        echo "<p><a href='download.php?file=$filename'> Download Resume </a></p>";
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood the question, this is very easy. Since you have the resume files in the upload folder. Just select the file name from the database and store on a variable lets say `$filename`, Like

```
$filename = $row['cv_filename']; // supposing $row contains the field of database
```

Then, use prefix the folder name in the anchor a link to that file.

```
$prefix = "uploads/resume";
echo "<a href='$prefix/$filename'>Download CV </a>";
```

Comment: On clicking the Download link, the correct link to file is shown in address bar of the browser but file is not downloading. Browser is showing an error:

The address wasn't understood.Firefox doesn't know how to open this address, because the protocol (c) isn't associated with any program.
        

        
        

  You might need to install other software to open this address.

Comment: @YogeshRawal, Can you show the link, that you used to initiate the download? Please provide full link together with `http(s)://`

Comment: I am working on my localhost server. In $prefix variable I given the address of the my download folder i.e. C:/wamp/www/Job Portal/downloads. And on clicking the download CV link, the address shown in the browser was: C:/wamp/www/Job Portal/downloads/abc.doc

Comment: @YogeshRawal, That is wrong, of course browser does not know how open that address. You don't need to include `C:/wamp/www/Job Portal/`, Just include `downloads/abc.doc`, browser will handle the rest.

Comment: It's done. Thanks. It is really very easy to implement. Regarding security issues is this method good to implement?

Comment: @YogeshRawal, To answer that, I need to know what type of security are you trying to implement?

Comment: I am talking about unwanted access to my download files. As we are providing the direct link to download files.

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Content-type: $type");
header("Content-length: $size");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
header("Content-Description: PHP Generated Data");
echo $data;
```

read full example @ http://onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2000/09/15/php_mysql.html?page=3

Comment: This link is for the files that are stored in database. But I am storing my files in the upload folder at my server. I want to know how to retrieve those files from the server for downloading option.